# LIKE for 2 fields in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql-like

May I know how to have LIKE with merging more than one field on mysql?
For example:

I would like to compare the search string with A and B field together.

> SELECT A, B from table WHERE (both A
>   B) LIKE 'search string'

Sorry guys, may be my question is not so detailed. For example:
A is 'i'
B is 'love'

How can i have a returned row be it the search result is 'i love' or 'love i'.

Thank you.

Comment: Example data and expected output?  What if search_string is half of A and half of B?

Comment: @Tauquir: Because REGEXP is the slowest means of finding the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, B from example WHERE (A LIKE 'search_string' and B LIKE 'search_string');
```

Comment: select A, B from example WHERE A REGEXP '[[:<:]]search_string[[:>:]]'and B REGEXP [[:<:]]search_string[[:>:]]);
 You can also write the regex. It will solve all your problem. But the problem with REGEXP is that , it slowest means of finding data (OMG Poines pointed it.)

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the syntax of your query to correctly check both fields:

```
SELECT A, B from `table` WHERE A LIKE 'search string' AND B LIKE 'search string'
```

But maybe you want some wildcards in the `LIKE` clause, otherwise it's a literal match no different than with `=`.

```
SELECT A, B from `table` WHERE A LIKE '%search string%' AND B LIKE '%search string%'
```

But be careful about using wildcards because they can prevent indexes from being used in your queries if they appear at the beginning of the expression, like in the example I gave.

### UPDATE:

Your question is worded a little ambiguously. It's possible that you meant merge `A` and `B` together and compare it against `search string`. In that case, you might try something like the following (in MySQL only):

```
SELECT A, B from `table` WHERE concat(A, B) LIKE '%search string%';
```

But don't expect it to perform well due to the function call and wildcards.

### UPDATE #2:

I see by your comment that what you actually want is this:

```
SELECT A, B from `table` WHERE 'search string' LIKE concat('%', A, '%')
    AND 'search string' LIKE concat('%', B, '%');
```

Comment: hi asaph, thanks for the reply. May be i should be more detail in my question. I want to search string to compare string together. for example if A is 'i' B is 'love', when the search is 'i love' or 'love i', a row will be displayed too. You have any idea? Thanks..

Comment: If `a = 'i'` and `b = 'i'`, the row will be returned.